# Using pre-defined class names in java

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to Java. I learnt that the names of predefined classes in java are not keywords and thus we can use those as identifiers.
I tried out the following code: (I know that that import is redundant)

```
import java.lang.*;

class Process{
    public Process(){
        System.out.println("Constructor of Process");
    }
}

public class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Process p = new Process();
    }
    
}
```

and the out put was:

```
Constructor of Process
```

However, when I replaced `import java.lang.*;` with import `java.lang.Process;`, I got an error cause it tried to instantiate the predefined Process class. I had assumed that the program will check scope by scope and will thus execute the userdefined class constructor in both cases. How am I wrong?

Comment: You imported java.lang.Process, and have a naming conflict with your Process class. These 2 classes cannot be imported under the same name at the same time, what's the problem? Use `java.lang.Process` when you want to reference the built in class, instead of importing it. Also what do you mean with "scope by scope"? For Java there is no difference between java.lang.Process and your.package.Process.

Comment: @adhan_e Scope by scope probably isn't the right term. I thought that the classes within the package will be checked first, then the imported ones. I want to know why java.lang.Process causes an error and java.lang.* does not, even though Process is imported in both statements.

Comment: No, it doesn't work like that. Refer to the spec - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5

`The declaration might be shadowed by a single-type-import declaration of a class or interface whose simple name is Vector; by a class or interface named Vector and declared in the package to which the compilation unit belongs; or any nested classes or interfaces. [...] (It would be unusual for any of these conditions to occur.)
`

Comment: In general, it's a bad idea to name classes the same thing as classes in `java.lang`. See [here](https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/JavaLangClash).

Comment: Also, note that `import java.lang.*;` is redundant, since everything in that package is automatically imported.

Comment: @adhnan_e Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.